# Flutter - How to open full screen keyboard in landscape mode

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout

How can I open a full screen keyboard in landscape mode like the one in the attached screenshot.

[image]
I tried adding my `TextField`s in `SingleChildScrollView` but it doesn't work for dialogs and my `TextFields` gets hidden by the keyboard.

**Edit:**

I am using a bottom sheet and the `TextField` works perfectly fine when focused in portrait mode, as shown in the screen below:
[image: portrait mode screenshot]

but in landscape mode `TextField` got hidden behind the keyboard.

[image: landscape mode screenshot without keyboard]
[image: landscape mode screenshot with keyboard]

Comment: So your problem is TextField get hidden by keyboard, right?

Comment: Yes, also the full screen keyboard is not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is to late, but it could help someone in the future.

Basically, the idea is to have normal portrait input field, but when device is rotated and when keyboard is opened then we want to show input field which will take whole space of the screen on top of other content on page (use Stack for that). So there are actually two input fields which are synced. Also, on landscape we don't want to show app bar because it takes a lot of space.

For detecting if keyboard is opened or not I've used [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) plugin.

Here is the final result:

**Landscape mode**

[image: Landscape mode of the landscape fullscreen keyboard]

**Portrait mode**

[image: Portait mode of the landscape fullscreen keyboard]

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var _keyboardShown = false;
  var _portraitController = TextEditingController();
  var _landscapeController = TextEditingController();

  var _focusNodeLandscape = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    var keyboardVisibilityController = KeyboardVisibilityController();

    // Listen for changes
    keyboardVisibilityController.onChange.listen((bool visible) {
      setState(() {
        _keyboardShown = visible;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _portraitController.dispose();
    _landscapeController.dispose();
    _focusNodeLandscape.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        // Build app bar according to orientation and keyboard visibility
        appBar: buildAppBar(),
        body: Stack(children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
              ),
              // Input field for portrait mode
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[600],
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _portraitController,
                  onChanged: (String text) {
                    _landscapeController.text = text;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // Possible landscape fullscreen input
          buildLandscapeFullscreenInput()
        ]));
  }

  Widget buildAppBar() {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape &&
        _keyboardShown) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return AppBar(
        title: Text("Landscape fullscreen keyboard PoC"),
      );
    }
  }

  Widget buildLandscapeFullscreenInput() {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape &&
        _keyboardShown) {
      // set focus to landscape fs input
      _focusNodeLandscape.requestFocus();

      return Container(
        color: Colors.grey[300],
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 3,
              right: 3,
              top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
              bottom: 3),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              // landscape fs input
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _landscapeController,
                  onChanged: (String text) {
                    _portraitController.text = text;
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: 99999,
                  autofocus: true,
                  focusNode: _focusNodeLandscape,
                ),
              ),
              // by clicking on button we dismiss keyboard
              KeyboardDismissOnTap(
                child: Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                      child: Text(
                        "Done",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      // un focus landscape fs input
      _focusNodeLandscape.unfocus();
      return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Full Screen Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2szOg.jpg)

First, create a method to show full screen dialog.

```
void showFullScreenKeyboard(BuildContext context,TextEditingController txtCtrl){
showDialog(context: context, builder:(context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Container()),
        Row(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                ),
                maxLines: null,
                autofocus: true,
                controller: txtCtrl,
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(onPressed: () {
              pop(context);
            }, child: const Text('Done')),
            const SizedBox(width: 200),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
);
```

},);
}

Then, implement this method at your desired TextField widget.
Use textfield's onTap() or GestureDector , as ur wish .

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  showFullScreenKeyboard(context,txtCustomerFeedbacks);
                },
                child: textFieldContainer(TextField(
                  enabled: false,
                  controller: txtCustomerFeedbacks,
                  maxLines: 5,
                  decoration:  InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      label: Text(language=='EN'?'Feedback':en2my['Feedback']!)
                  ),
                )),
              ),
```

[Original Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz8pU.jpg)